# Passing string of int in BaseModel

Tags: python, json, fastapi, pydantic

I'm trying to build a fastAPI with a POST method using BaseModel for data validation.
My (simplify) input data is a JSON that looks like:

```
{   
"name": "test",
"a": {
    "b": {
        "c": {
            "0": "Fl"
        },
        "400": {
            "0": 0
        }
    },
    "d": {
        "400": {
            "0": 56.3,
            "1": 78.3,
            "2": 96.1,
            "3": 101.58
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to create my BaseModel, PyCharm informs me that giving an 400, str(400) or '400' as key is an error. So I would have a class that would somewhat look like:

```
class D_0123(BaseModel):
    0: float
    1: float
    2: float
    3: float

class BD(BaseModel):
    400: Dict[D_0123]

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    a: Dict[BD]
```

PyCharm gives me an error : 'An illegal target for a variable allocation'.
I know that JSON can not take int as keys as transforms them automatically to "int".

So I wonder if what I want to do is possible? Is there a workaround?

Thank you all for your time!

Have a great day!

Comment: Your input data are valid JSON, and PyCharm wouldn't complain about this. Please edit your question posting the BaseModel creation code so that we know how we can help.

Comment: @tzot I added the part of the BaseModel that raises the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python syntax that pydantic (and therefore FastAPI) takes advantage of is:

```
class SomeName:
   attribute_name: type
```

The `BaseModel` superclass probably has a custom metaclass (or a custom `__init_subclass__` method) that reads the names of the class attributes and their associated types. The attribute_name **must** follow Python's identifier semantics, so it must start with an alphabetic and continue with alphanumerics+underscore.

Therefore I believe that normally¹ you can't take advantage of “automatic” validation using keys unacceptable as identifiers, and you'll have to validate the field contents with your own code.
Or you could change the convention and any key that is comprised of numerics starts with an underscore, if pydantic does not ignore underscore-prefixed class members.

¹ I say “normally” because you can replace:

```
class D_0123(BaseModel):
    0: float
    1: float
    2: float
    3: float
```

with:

```
D_0123 = type('D_0123', (BaseModel,), {"0": None, "1": None, "2": None, "3": None})
D_0123.__annotations__ = {"0": float, "1": float, "2": float, "3": float}
```

but I very much doubt that it would work as you would expect; it depends on the definition of `BaseModel` and how much processing is done during the subclass (i.e. D_0123) creation.

PS See also [Bodies of arbitrary dicts](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-nested-models/#bodies-of-arbitrary-dicts) from the FastAPI documentation.

Comment: Python 3.9 and hence include a `typing.Annotated` type that perhaps could be used as values in the dict 3rd argument of `type()`, but I work with Python 3.8 and can't test this.

Comment: Ok I understand why it's not working, but I'm not sure to understand what your 2 added lines do and the link with the quantity of processing during the subclass creation. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: `type` called with three arguments: name, superclasses, dict is the method to create a new class with name `name`, subclassing `superclasses` and with the dictionary `dict` containing the class members (key attribute name, value attribute value). Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type for more info. Assigning another dict to `D_0123.__annotations__` is how to mimic what Python does under the hood when class members have type annotations.